# cmd nested in backticks processed from sudo?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sudo, dash

Are nested `` `commands` `` using (deprecated) backticks executed with root permissions (from `sudo` command line) while command substitution `$(...)` is not?

for example

```
sudo mount `blkid -u /dev/sda1` ...
sudo mount `sudo blkid -u /dev/sda1` ...
```

vs

```
sudo mount $(blkid -u /dev/sda1) ...
sudo mount $(sudo blkid -u /dev/sda1) ...
```

is there a difference between methods? i am not even quite sure which of the four lines is the right usage (regarding `sudo`, not blkid it's just pseudo code). or is it shell dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` `...` `` and `$(...)` are the same thing with different syntax, one if from the Bourne shell, the other from the Korn shell, the former is deprecated but still supported by Bourne-like shells for backward compatibility with the ancient Bourne shell.

Other shells have different syntax for that. For instance, `fish` has `(...)` and `rc`/`es` have `` `cmd `` or `` `{more complex cmd} ``, or `` `(sep){cmd} `` to specify different splitting behaviour. `ksh93` and `mksh` also have `${ ...; }` (no subshell) variant.

In any case, that's syntax in the shell language, so you need a shell to interpret it and perform the command substitution.

In:

```
sudo cmd1 `cmd2`
```

In Bourne-like shells, the shell

- runs `cmd2` in a child process with its output redirected to a pipe
- reads the output of that cmd from the other end of the pipe,
- removes the trailing newline characters,
- splits the result according to `$IFS`
- perform filename generation on the resulting words (except in `zsh`; some ksh variants also perform brace expansion)
- and then passes the resulting words as separate arguments to a `sudo` command executed in another child process.

`sudo` then changes uids and runs the command it is being passed as argument.

If you wanted `cmd2`, to be run with the different uid, you'd need `sudo` to run a shell to interpret the shell code that performs the command substitution:

```
sudo sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2)'
sudo fish -c 'cmd1 (cmd2)'
sudo rc -c 'cmd1 `cmd2'
```

and so on.

Note that in Bourne-like shells, command substitution is still performed inside double quotes, so do **not** do:

<strike>`sudo sh -c "cmd1 $(cmd2)"`</strike>

First, that would not run `cmd2` as `root`, but also the output of `cmd2` (this time, not subjected to split+glob as it's within quotes), would be interpreted as `sh` code, so would typically constitute a command injection vulnerability. For instance, if `cmd2` outputs `$(reboot)`, the `sh` invoked by `sudo` would be asked to interpret `cmd1 $(reboot)` and reboot.

Similarly, don't do <strike>`sudo sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2) '"$var"`</strike> or <strike>`sudo sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2 '"$var"')'`</strike> if you want to pass the contents of variables of *your* shell (as opposed to the one started by `sudo`) to `cmd1` or `cmd2`. Instead, pass the contents of those variables as extra *arguments* to `sh` (not inside the *code* argument), or via environment variables (so they become variables of the shell started by `sudo` as well):

```
sudo sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2) "$1"' sh "$var"
sudo VAR="$var" sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2) "$VAR"'

sudo sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2 "$1")' sh "$var"
sudo VAR="$var" sh -c 'cmd1 $(cmd2 "$VAR")'
```

Here, you can always also do:

```
sudo cmd1 $(sudo cmd2) "$var"
sudo cmd1 $(sudo cmd2 "$var")
```

That is have *your* shell run both commands through two separate invocations of `sudo` so both be run with elevated privileges.

As hinted above, in Bourne-like shells (but that also applies, though differently, to csh-like shells), unquoted command substitution is subject to split+glob, so you'd only leave `$(cmd2)` unquoted in `cmd1 $(cmd2)` if `cmd2` is outputting a `$IFS` delimited list of wildcard patterns. If you want the output of `cmd2` (without the trailing newline characters) to be passed as a whole as *one* argument to `cmd1`, you'd want `cmd1 "$(cmd2)"` or more likely `cmd1 -- "$(cmd2)"` to make sure that argument is not treated as an option (assuming `cmd1` supports that `--` end-of-option marker).

So for your particular use case, that would be:

```
sudo DEVICE="$device" sh -c 'mount -- "$(blkid -u -- "$DEVICE")"'
```

Or to call `mount` only if `blkid` succeeds:

```
sudo DEVICE="$device" sh -c '
  output=$(blkid -u -- "$DEVICE") &&
    mount -- "$output"
'
```

Comment: thx, are you sure about word splitting? i have read different about `$(...)`

Comment: @alecxs, try: `IFS=':+ '; printf '<%s>\n' $(echo '/*:a b++{a,b}+c')` in various Bourne/Korn-like shells. You'll find some variation when it comes to globbing and brace expansion, but all do the splitting as it's a common usage pattern. You'll find some variation on how that splitting is done though (even more if you consider non-Bourne-like shells).

Comment: yes, i have tested myself already. in past i always quoted but there was answer somewhere stating that word splitting is not performed. but it was about assigning strings like `var=$()` maybe i misunderstood that completely (can't find that answer anymore)

Comment: @alecxs, see also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) (and other Q&A linked within) and [What are the contexts where Bash doesn't perform word splitting and globbing?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/441690) for details.

Comment: thx.. there i found the [confusing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131784) answer again.. misunderstood, my fault!